# Why is Haskell Stack hanging while attempting to build my project?

Tags: macos, haskell, build, haskell-stack

Running `stack build` in a project that should build correctly (it works on other developers' machines, and has worked on mine in the past) hangs on the same library (`regex-posix-0.95.2`) every time.

I'm running macos 10.14.4.

I've already tried `stack clean --full` and reinstalling stack from scratch. Attempting to `stack upgrade` hangs at `Download complete, testing executable`.

Here's the output of `stack build --verbose`:

```
stack build --verbose
1.9.3 x86_64
Compiled with:
- Cabal-2.4.0.1
- Glob-0.9.3
- HUnit-1.6.0.0
- QuickCheck-2.11.3
- StateVar-1.1.1.1
- aeson-1.3.1.1
- aeson-compat-0.3.9
- annotated-wl-pprint-0.7.0
- ansi-terminal-0.8.2
- ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2
- array-0.5.2.0
- asn1-encoding-0.9.5
- asn1-parse-0.9.4
- asn1-types-0.3.2
- async-2.2.1
- attoparsec-0.13.2.2
- attoparsec-iso8601-1.0.1.0
- auto-update-0.1.4
- base-4.11.1.0
- base-compat-0.10.5
- base-orphans-0.7
- base-prelude-1.3
- base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6
- base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1
- basement-0.0.8
- bifunctors-5.5.3
- binary-0.8.5.1
- bindings-uname-0.1
- bitarray-0.0.1.1
- blaze-builder-0.4.1.0
- blaze-html-0.9.1.1
- blaze-markup-0.8.2.2
- byteable-0.1.1
- bytestring-0.10.8.2
- call-stack-0.1.0
- case-insensitive-1.2.0.11
- cereal-0.5.7.0
- clock-0.7.2
- colour-2.3.4
- comonad-5.0.4
- conduit-1.3.1
- conduit-extra-1.3.0
- connection-0.2.8
- containers-0.5.11.0
- contravariant-1.4.1
- cookie-0.4.4
- cryptohash-0.11.9
- cryptohash-sha256-0.11.101.0
- cryptonite-0.25
- cryptonite-conduit-0.2.2
- data-default-class-0.1.2.0
- deepseq-1.4.3.0
- digest-0.0.1.2
- directory-1.3.1.5
- distributive-0.5.3
- dlist-0.8.0.5
- easy-file-0.2.2
- echo-0.1.3
- ed25519-0.0.5.0
- either-5.0.1
- exceptions-0.10.0
- extra-1.6.13
- fast-logger-2.4.11
- file-embed-0.0.10.1
- filelock-0.1.1.2
- filepath-1.4.2
- free-5.0.2
- fsnotify-0.3.0.1
- generic-deriving-1.12.2
- ghc-boot-th-8.4.4
- ghc-prim-0.5.2.0
- hackage-security-0.5.3.0
- hashable-1.2.7.0
- haskell-src-exts-1.20.3
- haskell-src-meta-0.8.0.3
- hfsevents-0.1.6
- hourglass-0.2.12
- hpack-0.31.1
- hpc-0.6.0.3
- hspec-2.5.5
- hspec-core-2.5.5
- hspec-discover-2.5.5
- hspec-expectations-0.8.2
- hspec-smallcheck-0.5.2
- http-api-data-0.3.8.1
- http-client-0.5.14
- http-client-tls-0.3.5.3
- http-conduit-2.3.2
- http-types-0.12.2
- infer-license-0.2.0
- integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
- integer-logarithms-1.0.2.2
- lifted-base-0.2.3.12
- logict-0.6.0.2
- megaparsec-6.5.0
- memory-0.14.18
- microlens-0.4.9.1
- microlens-th-0.4.2.3
- mime-types-0.1.0.8
- mintty-0.1.2
- monad-control-1.0.2.3
- monad-logger-0.3.30
- monad-loops-0.4.3
- mono-traversable-1.0.9.0
- mtl-2.2.2
- mustache-2.3.0
- neat-interpolation-0.3.2.2
- network-2.6.3.6
- network-uri-2.6.1.0
- old-locale-1.0.0.7
- old-time-1.1.0.3
- open-browser-0.2.1.0
- optparse-applicative-0.14.3.0
- parsec-3.1.13.0
- parser-combinators-1.0.0
- path-0.6.1
- path-io-1.3.3
- path-pieces-0.2.1
- pem-0.2.4
- persistent-2.8.2
- persistent-sqlite-2.8.2
- persistent-template-2.5.4
- pretty-1.1.3.6
- primitive-0.6.3.0
- process-1.6.3.0
- profunctors-5.2.2
- project-template-0.2.0.1
- quickcheck-io-0.2.0
- random-1.1
- regex-applicative-0.3.3
- regex-applicative-text-0.1.0.1
- resource-pool-0.2.3.2
- resourcet-1.2.2
- retry-0.7.7.0
- rio-0.1.5.0
- rts-1.0
- safe-0.3.17
- scientific-0.3.6.2
- semigroupoids-5.2.2
- semigroups-0.18.5
- setenv-0.1.1.3
- silently-1.2.5
- smallcheck-1.1.5
- socks-0.5.6
- split-0.2.3.3
- stm-2.4.5.1
- stm-chans-3.0.0.4
- store-0.5.0.1
- store-core-0.4.4
- streaming-commons-0.2.1.0
- syb-0.7
- tagged-0.8.5
- tar-0.5.1.0
- template-haskell-2.13.0.0
- temporary-1.3
- text-1.2.3.1
- text-metrics-0.3.0
- tf-random-0.5
- th-abstraction-0.2.8.0
- th-expand-syns-0.4.4.0
- th-lift-0.7.11
- th-lift-instances-0.1.11
- th-orphans-0.13.6
- th-reify-many-0.1.8
- th-utilities-0.2.0.1
- time-1.8.0.2
- time-locale-compat-0.1.1.5
- tls-1.4.1
- transformers-0.5.5.0
- transformers-base-0.4.5.2
- transformers-compat-0.6.2
- typed-process-0.2.3.0
- unicode-transforms-0.3.5
- unix-2.7.2.2
- unix-compat-0.5.1
- unix-time-0.3.8
- unliftio-0.2.8.1
- unliftio-core-0.1.2.0
- unordered-containers-0.2.9.0
- uri-bytestring-0.3.2.1
- uuid-types-1.0.3
- vector-0.12.0.1
- vector-algorithms-0.7.0.4
- void-0.7.2
- x509-1.7.5
- x509-store-1.6.7
- x509-system-1.6.6
- x509-validation-1.6.11
- yaml-0.10.4.0
- zip-archive-0.3.3
- zlib-0.6.2

Warning: this is an unsupported build that may use different versions of
dependencies and GHC than the officially released binaries, and therefore may
not behave identically.  If you encounter problems, please try the latest
official build by running 'stack upgrade --force-download'.

2019-05-06 15:34:43.787917: [debug] Checking for project config at: /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/stack.yaml
2019-05-06 15:34:43.788935: [debug] Loading project config file stack.yaml
2019-05-06 15:34:43.790456: [debug] Decoding build plan from: /Users/marnold/.stack/build-plan/lts-9.21.yaml
2019-05-06 15:34:43.790519: [debug] Trying to decode /Users/marnold/.stack/build-plan-cache/lts-9.21.cache
2019-05-06 15:34:43.795490: [debug] Success decoding /Users/marnold/.stack/build-plan-cache/lts-9.21.cache
2019-05-06 15:34:43.797255: [debug] Potential GHC builds: standard
2019-05-06 15:34:43.797339: [debug] Found already installed GHC builds: standard
2019-05-06 15:34:43.798120: [debug] Asking GHC for its version
2019-05-06 15:34:43.798403: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --numeric-version
2019-05-06 15:34:43.799254: [debug] Getting Cabal package version
2019-05-06 15:34:43.799975: [debug] Getting global package database location
2019-05-06 15:34:43.800054: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version
2019-05-06 15:34:43.800731: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
2019-05-06 15:34:43.942529: [debug] Process finished in 142ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version
2019-05-06 15:34:43.942739: [debug] Process finished in 142ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
2019-05-06 15:34:43.956352: [debug] Process finished in 158ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --numeric-version
2019-05-06 15:34:43.956423: [debug] GHC version is: ghc-8.0.2
2019-05-06 15:34:43.956499: [debug] Resolving package entries
2019-05-06 15:34:43.956606: [debug] Trying to decode /Users/marnold/.stack/loaded-snapshot-cache/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/lts-9.21.cache
2019-05-06 15:34:43.996883: [debug] Success decoding /Users/marnold/.stack/loaded-snapshot-cache/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/lts-9.21.cache
2019-05-06 15:34:44.000908: [debug] Starting to execute command inside EnvConfig
2019-05-06 15:34:44.000979: [debug] Parsing the targets
2019-05-06 15:34:44.001189: [debug] Running hpack on /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/package.yaml
2019-05-06 15:34:44.026786: [debug] hpack output unchanged in /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/authentication-service.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.040562: [debug] Trying to decode /Users/marnold/.stack/indices/Hackage/01-index.cache
2019-05-06 15:34:44.256229: [debug] Success decoding /Users/marnold/.stack/indices/Hackage/01-index.cache
2019-05-06 15:34:44.289569: [debug] Start: getPackageFiles /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/authentication-service.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.358574: [debug] Finished in 69ms: getPackageFiles /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/authentication-service.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.358912: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-caches/lib: /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-caches/lib: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.373278: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-caches/exe-authentication-service: /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-caches/exe-authentication-service: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.374206: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-caches/exe-authentication-service-rotate-keys: /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-caches/exe-authentication-service-rotate-keys: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.378317: [debug] Start: getPackageFiles /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/downloaded/IzWmITn_pxL3/amazonka/amazonka.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.406152: [debug] Finished in 28ms: getPackageFiles /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/downloaded/IzWmITn_pxL3/amazonka/amazonka.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.407749: [debug] Start: getPackageFiles /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/downloaded/VaZUmJdBvu9Z/jose.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.458370: [debug] Finished in 51ms: getPackageFiles /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/downloaded/VaZUmJdBvu9Z/jose.cabal
2019-05-06 15:34:44.459843: [debug] Finding out which packages are already installed
2019-05-06 15:34:44.460563: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot
2019-05-06 15:34:44.509236: [debug] Process finished in 48ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot
2019-05-06 15:34:44.510078: [debug] Ignoring package haskeline due to wanting version 0.7.4.2 instead of 0.7.3.0
2019-05-06 15:34:44.510146: [debug] Ignoring package terminfo due to wanting version 0.4.1.0 instead of 0.4.0.2
2019-05-06 15:34:44.510190: [debug] Ignoring package xhtml due to wanting version 3000.2.2 instead of 3000.2.1
2019-05-06 15:34:44.510393: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643387: [debug] Process finished in 133ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643669: [debug] Ignoring package jose, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643745: [debug] Ignoring package test-fixture, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643800: [debug] Ignoring package haskell-src-meta, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643852: [debug] Ignoring package th-orphans, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643917: [debug] Ignoring package quickcheck-instances, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.643982: [debug] Ignoring package concise, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644052: [debug] Ignoring package amazonka-s3, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644100: [debug] Ignoring package amazonka, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644155: [debug] Ignoring package amazonka-core, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644210: [debug] Ignoring package lens, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644257: [debug] Ignoring package persistent-postgresql, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644301: [debug] Ignoring package persistent-template, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644742: [debug] Ignoring package persistent, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644797: [debug] Ignoring package xml-conduit, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644849: [debug] Ignoring package postgresql-simple, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.644996: [debug] Ignoring package resource-pool, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645087: [debug] Ignoring package aeson-compat, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645146: [debug] Ignoring package hspec, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645192: [debug] Ignoring package hspec-core, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645258: [debug] Ignoring package quickcheck-io, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645334: [debug] Ignoring package QuickCheck, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645382: [debug] Ignoring package tf-random, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.645426: [debug] Ignoring package monad-logger, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.648628: [debug] Ignoring package ini, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.648739: [debug] Ignoring package http-conduit, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.648897: [debug] Ignoring package conduit-extra, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.648960: [debug] Ignoring package servant-client, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.649046: [debug] Ignoring package servant-server, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.649377: [debug] Ignoring package wai-app-static, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.649534: [debug] Ignoring package warp, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.649628: [debug] Ignoring package wai-extra, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.649852: [debug] Ignoring package http-date, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.650489: [debug] Ignoring package servant, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.650561: [debug] Ignoring package http-api-data, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.650616: [debug] Ignoring package uri-bytestring, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.650685: [debug] Ignoring package th-lift-instances, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.650755: [debug] Ignoring package attoparsec-iso8601, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.650972: [debug] Ignoring package hlint, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651038: [debug] Ignoring package yaml, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651112: [debug] Ignoring package aeson, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651162: [debug] Ignoring package monad-journal, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651225: [debug] Ignoring package either, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651302: [debug] Ignoring package attoparsec, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651392: [debug] Ignoring package vector, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651484: [debug] Ignoring package scientific, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651590: [debug] Ignoring package conduit, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651804: [debug] Ignoring package MonadRandom, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.651983: [debug] Ignoring package primitive, from (InstalledTo Snap,"/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb/"), due to wrong location: (Just (InstalledTo Snap),Local)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.652703: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
2019-05-06 15:34:44.719839: [debug] Process finished in 67ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /Users/marnold/Code/lambda/authentication-service/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
2019-05-06 15:34:44.722534: [debug] Constructing the build plan
2019-05-06 15:34:44.851193: [debug] Checking if we are going to build multiple executables with the same name
2019-05-06 15:34:44.851459: [debug] Executing the build plan
2019-05-06 15:34:44.854074: [debug] Getting global package database location
2019-05-06 15:34:44.854179: [debug] Run process: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
2019-05-06 15:34:44.894256: [debug] Process finished in 40ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
2019-05-06 15:34:44.895126: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /Users/marnold/.stack/precompiled/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/1.24.2.0/regex-posix-0.95.2@sha256:4fba55cdae7fb6c11ee2f5e823e56cc5fc30d7041edeef4c81f7f26b9235d624,3794/84y8nQstWbhLt6U-nBiCnfQ_PrWr5ann9qOnwUBs-I0=: /Users/marnold/.stack/precompiled/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/1.24.2.0/regex-posix-0.95.2@sha256:4fba55cdae7fb6c11ee2f5e823e56cc5fc30d7041edeef4c81f7f26b9235d624,3794/84y8nQstWbhLt6U-nBiCnfQ_PrWr5ann9qOnwUBs-I0=: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.908903: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-config-cache: /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-config-cache: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.909117: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-cabal-mod: /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-cabal-mod: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
2019-05-06 15:34:44.909266: [info] regex-posix-0.95.2: configure
2019-05-06 15:34:44.910644: [debug] Run process within /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/: /Users/marnold/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/doc/regex-posix-0.95.2 --htmldir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/doc/regex-posix-0.95.2 --haddockdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/doc/regex-posix-0.95.2 --dependency=array=array-0.5.1.1 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.1 --dependency=containers=containers-0.5.7.1 --dependency=regex-base=regex-base-0.93.2-AYjYAsBidAc8f5XNm9b2Aa --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
2019-05-06 15:34:46.975642: [debug] Process finished in 2065ms: /Users/marnold/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/Users/marnold/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/doc/regex-posix-0.95.2 --htmldir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/doc/regex-posix-0.95.2 --haddockdir=/Users/marnold/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.21/8.0.2/doc/regex-posix-0.95.2 --dependency=array=array-0.5.1.1 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.1 --dependency=containers=containers-0.5.7.1 --dependency=regex-base=regex-base-0.93.2-AYjYAsBidAc8f5XNm9b2Aa --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
2019-05-06 15:34:46.975924: [debug] Encoding /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-config-cache
2019-05-06 15:34:46.976439: [debug] Finished writing /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-config-cache
2019-05-06 15:34:46.976505: [debug] Encoding /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-cabal-mod
2019-05-06 15:34:46.976849: [debug] Finished writing /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-cabal-mod
2019-05-06 15:34:46.976968: [info] regex-posix-0.95.2: build
2019-05-06 15:34:46.977205: [debug] Run process within /private/var/folders/21/zwczf5r93z11lv5bpxp25rwm0000gn/T/stack-25f25e16a2305aa4/regex-posix-0.95.2/: /Users/marnold/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Progress 0/4
```

Comment: Have you tried blowing away stack cache? Worked for me in the past.

Comment: is that different than `stack clean --full`?

Comment: also, I've tried erasing the entire project `.stack-work` directory.

Comment: tried deleting ~/.stack as well, now most stack commands hang at `Configuring GHC...`

Comment: might also be just reaaaaly slow...

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is due to a package simply taking a long time to compile, not an actual bug. This comes up most often with the Cabal library. There are two good ways to check if this is what's happening:

- Add the `--interleaved-output` flag, which will show you the progress of compiling individual modules in dependencies. This flag will be on by default in Stack 2, in large part due to this issue.
- Check your activity monitor/`top`/etc program and confirm that GHC is in fact using significant CPU.

Comment: I can't even get to the point where I'm compiling packages anymore. I deleted and reinstalled stack (using brew--my attempts with wget and curl as per https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/) hang immediately after calling `stack`), but now it gets stuck during the `Configuring GHC...` stage. Activity monitor shows it at zero cpu, and a thread sample appears to show all threads either waiting or polling. I've left it sitting there for several hours, with no change.

Comment: I see you opened up an issue on Github about this problem, it's probably best to discuss that there. For others: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4815